# CodeIgniter missing argument despite argument being passed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I keep getting the error:

> Missing argument 1 for AdminPanel::viewUser()

Issue is that the url itself looks roughly like this:

```
domain.com/AdminPanel/viewUser/1
```

Yet, for some reason, a value is not passed to the controller, despite in the controller it is defined as

```
public function viewUser($id)
```

If I set a default value to the ID, it will only use the default value, not the values passed through the url

Comment: you can set routes and check value in controller side.

Comment: What version of CI you using?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 am using 3.1.5

Comment: @NikunjRathod care to expand that answer? Cause I tried it and it didn't work. Routing was my first tought too.

Comment: OK `viewUser($id = NULL)` I also think your naming your file and classes wrong make sure only the first letter is upper case only on filename and class name explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Once that done echo $id if get nothing then you need to create a route for it.

Comment: can you put the controller code with only one method viewUser, so that we can find the problem more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error. I had been using

```
  function _remap($method_name = 'index')
  {
    if(!method_exists($this, $method_name)){
         $this->index();
    }
    else{
         $this->{$method_name}();
    }
  }
```

To redirect user to certain page if they are trying to call a method that does not exist. Removed this one and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value from URL in controller. You need to mention some line on Routes.php see below :

```
$route['Admin/viewUser/(:num)'] = 'Admin/viewUser/$1';
```

It will automaitcally get the passing value in your method $id params

Comment: Doesn't work. I did change the Admin part to AdminPanel (the name of the controller) and I still keep getting the same error.

Comment: also make sure you controller class and file name must be upper case .

Answer (score 0):

Clean and simple it is expecting that, it needs variable in function, for some or other reason if it's not passed then

try doing this always.

```
<?php

public function viewUser($id="")
{
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to pass it as param, Please use it as uri segment. It will declare and assign as follows:-

```
$this->uri->segment(3, '0');
```

Now remove `$id` from function.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, in the event the code is re-used or the URI changed in the future.